# Object's unique integer or string identifier (hash)

Tags: actionscript-3, haxe

Is there a method or other native way to get or store a unique identifier for an object? (perhaps with haxe native access or the actionscript API).

The reason is to facilitate contemplation about the Dictionary and other datastructures that operate on the uniqueness of an object index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your are using Dictionaries, the object itself could be used as key, so there you have your uniqueness.

```
var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
var obj:SomeClass = new SomeClass();
dict[obj] = "whatever";
```

For other data structures, you could try to generate a sequential number statically. In many cases, this should be enough, I think.

Something like:

```
class UniqueKey {
  private static var _key:int = 0;
  public static function getNextKey():int {
    return ++_key;
  }
}
```

And to use it:

```
var obj:SomeClass = new SomeClass();
obj.unique = UniqueKey.getNextKey();
```

Comment: Though the above is an explanation of the documented patterns with regards to this issue, I was asking about a native id for any object. This does not appear to be provided by the Flash runtime.

Comment: @dlots. There's no native way (at least that I'm aware of). Other than the above, you could implement some hashcode (I'm thinking Java's `hashcode()` interface/method). But this won't guarantee uniqueness (especially for objects whose fields share the same values). I'd go with a Dictionary all things considered (the int option could work but it could be a lot of work for, perhaps, a little gain).

Comment: I am aware of the Dictionary and the patterns specified. :) But there are other abstractions reliant on the uniqueness of an object other than a hash table. Oh well, I guess you gotta do it manually.